# Share image using share extension

Tags: ios, nsurlsession, ios-app-extension, nsurlsessionuploadtask

While sharing an image with a share extension, I am facing an issue. I have done all the steps that enable the app group in both the extension and the container profile. I followed these [steps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25658666/share-extension-not-uploading-full-size-images) to implement sharing code in the extension.

The error I'm seeing is:

```
Unable to bootstrap_look_up port with name me.com.companyname.share.gsEvents: unknown error code (1102)
```

and also

```
Application me.com.appName is not handling a background URLSession but we still received a signal to deliver pending events
```

Answer (score 0):

App can share information with its extensions using App Group. App Groups are the shared container which your app and extension can use to share information like User Session, Contacts and can also hold data which is being uploaded to server.

User Session information is required to extension to communicate with server on behalf of logged in user. You can share any kind of extra information using shared container (App Group).

http://muhammadzahidimran.com/2016/12/08/how-to-track-progress-of-an-upload-started-by-share-extension/

Comment: I want to share images and video from share extension to my app then I have to use those images in my application flow. If it is possible with AppGroup please help me. I stuck on it and App group is throwing some error regarding invalid entitlement. I setup as suggested on internet.